# Hack the elections

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic

You're a professional hacker and your boss has just ordered you to help a candidate win an upcoming election. Your task is to alter the voting machines data to boost the candidate's results.

Voting machines store voting results as two integers : the number of votes for your candidate (`v1`) and the number of votes for their opponent (`v2`).

After weeks of research, you have found a security hole in the system and you can increase the value of `v1` by an integer `x`, and decrease the value of `v2` by the same `x`.
But there is a constraint, you have to keep the security hash code constant:

- security hash code : `(v1 + v2*2) modulo 7`

Also, the value for `x` must be minimal so your changes can go unnoticed.

Your program should accept as input `v1` and `v2` ; it should output the optimal value for `x` so `v1>v2`.

There are some cases for which you cannot hack the results; you don't have to handle them (this might lead to problems with your boss, but that's another story).

**Test cases**

```
100,123 --> 14
47,23 --> 0
40,80 --> 21
62,62 --> 7
1134,2145 --> 511
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51614/discussion-on-question-by-super-chafouin-hack-the-elections).

Comment: Also, to the close voters: This is perfectly on-topic. If you don't like it, you can downvote it.

Comment: What a secure hash function!

Comment: Can you assume the inputs are followed by `.0` (Like `100.0 123.0`)?

Answer (score 21):

## Python 2, 30 bytes

```py
lambda u,t:max(0,(t-u)/14*7+7)
```

`u` is our votes, `t` is their votes.

Comment: Couldn't `(t-u)/14*7` be just `(t-u)/2`?

Comment: Oh, wait, nevermind, Py2 does integer division

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Nope. Consider `t-u == 16`. Then 16/14*7 = 7, but 16/2 = 8. Also, you aren't running as Python 2.

Comment: @orlp I don't know which one to ask, so I'll ask both of you, can you please explain to me how you thought of this? `y<x?0:(y-x)/2-(y-x)/2%7+7;`, I thought that I should take the difference split it in half, and then find the nearest multiple of 7. How did you arrive to this?

Comment: the same solution is above

Answer (score 20):

### Python 2, 30 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:max((b-a)/14*7+7,0)
```

Comment: After fixing the bug we basically have the same answer =/

Comment: @orlp Yeah, I think this is just the way to write the expression. Unless a recursive solution is shorter, which I doubt.

Comment: @xnor I don't know which one to ask, so I'll ask both of you, can you please explain to me how you thought of this? `y<x?0:(y-x)/2-(y-x)/2%7+7;`, I thought that I should take the difference split it in half, and then find the nearest multiple of 7. How did you arrive to this?

Comment: @WadeTyler We're looking the the smallest multiple of 7 that is strictly greater than half the difference. To find that from `(b-a)/2`, we do `/7*7` to round downs to the nearest multiple of 7, and then `+7` to go up to the next up. That is, unless the we would get a negative number, in which case we're winning anyway can just do 0. Taking the `max` with 0 achieves this. Some of it was also just tweaking the expression and running it on the test cases to see what works.

Comment: @xnor What I don't understand is why `/7*7`?

Comment: @xnor I pretty much thought of the same thing except I don't know how to transform my formula to look like yours.

Comment: @WadeTyler The `/7*7` is a kind of expression that shows up often enough in golfing that I think of it as an idiom. The idea is the `n/7` takes the floor of `n/7`, i.e. finds how many whole multiples of `7` fit within `n`. Then, multiplying by `7` brings it to that number multiple of `7`.

Comment: @xnor I got it. Thanks a lot. I don't like using formulas without knowing what they mean, so I usually spend as much time as needed to fully understand them.

Comment: In ruby: instead of (b-a)/14*7+7 I am using (a-b)/14*-7, which should work in python too and save a byte.

Comment: @GB That doesn't work if the vote is tied (like `62,62`).

Comment: Oops, you are right, I didn't check that test case...

Comment: just out of curiosity, how does this handle inputs where a is greater than b but by less than 7 (ie a=100 b=98)? if  i understood the tests correctly, the returned value should be 0

Comment: @JackAmmo That example gives `-2/7*7`, and since Python floor-division rounds towards negative infinity, `2/7` is -1, so `7*-7+1` is 0. So, both sides give 0, which works out fine.

Answer (score 13):

### Mathematica, 22 bytes

```
0//.x_/;2x<=#2-#:>x+7&
```

Pure function with arguments `#` and `#2`. Hits maximum recursion depth if the discrepancy is more than `7*2^16 = 458752`.

### Explanation

```
0                       Starting with 0,
 //.                    repeatedly apply the following rule until there is no change:
    x_                    if you see an expression x
      /;                    such that
        2x<=#2-#            2x <= #2-# (equivalently, #+x <= #2-x)
                :>        then replace it with
                  x+7       x+7 (hash is preserved only by multiples of 7)
                     &  End the function definition
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation for all this?

Comment: @Pavel Maybe your comment has continued getting upvotes because my explanation was unclear?

Comment: I thought it was fine, but then again I also know Mathematica.

Comment: @Pavel Well it's better now :)

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
IH:7‘×7»0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@@/pYWX@qGHG4enmh3Yb/P//P9rQwEBHwdDIOFZHIdrEXEcBygIKWhiAWGZGOgpmRiCWoaGxCVDe0MQ0FgA)

#### How it works

```
IH:7‘×7»0  Main link. Argument: [v1, v2]

I          Increments; compute [v2 - v1].
 H         Halve the result.
  :7       Perform integer division by 7.
    ‘      Increment the quotient.
     ×7    Multiply the result by 7.
       »0  Take the maximum of the product and 0.
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 13 bytes

```
7;;τ((-\*+0kM
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/actually#@29ubX2@RUNDN0ZL2yDb9/9/QwMDLkMjYwA)

Uses the same `max((b-a)/14*7+7,0)` formula that xnor and orlp use.

Explanation:

```
7;;τ((-\*+0kM
7;;            3 copies of 7
   τ           double one of them
    ((-        bring the inputs back to the top, take their difference
       \*+     integer divide by 14, multiply by 7, add 7
          0kM  maximum of that and 0
```

Comment: *Actually*, this is a great answer

Comment: I feel like the name of this language was intentional to make the submission titles sound like punchlines: "Guys, _Actually_, this is 13 bytes! Come on!"

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Actually, that's correct.

Answer (score 6):

### Groovy, 41 <s>37</s> bytes

```groovy
{x,y->[Math.floor((y-x)/14)*7+7,0].max()}
```

This is an unnamed closure. Thanks to `xnor` and `orlp` for the formula and `James holderness` for pointing out a bug.

The previous solution used `intdiv()` for integer division but it behaves differently from `//` used in python.

[Try it here!](http://ideone.com/cDX7Nh)

Answer (score 5):

## Haskell, <s>30</s> 24 bytes

```
a#b=max 0$div(b-a)14*7+7
```

An infix operator taking the number of votes of your preferred candidate first. Uses the same logic as the other answers of rounding with `/14*7+7`.

Comment: Finding the first value that meets a condition is a good use for `until`: `a#b=until(\c->a+c>b-c)(+7)0`, or better `a%b=until(>(b-a)/2)(+7)0`. Though an arithmetic formula is still likely shorter.

Comment: Note that apart from xnor's shorter alternatives `head[...]` can almost always be shortened to `[...]!!0`

Comment: @xnor: your until solution returns a `Fractional a`, I'm not sure if that is accepted. With `div` it is though shorter, so thanks! Eventually used the mathematical approach - and indeed, it was another two bytes shorter than until. @Laikoni: nice golfing, didn't know about that one, will remember it.

Answer (score 4):

## J, 15 bytes

```
0>.7+7*14<.@%~-
```

Kinda interesting, I was working on a problem and I thought I had a solution but as it turns out I was wrong. Oh well. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/j#@5@mYGulYGCnZ65trmVoYqPnoFqny1WSWlxSDJIwNDJWMDQwULBWADJMzIG0hYGCCYhvZgRCQHFDE1MFQ0NjE67U5Ix8BQ0dPYU0fYXUxOQMTQWwMf//AwA) Here's the result:

```
   f =: 0>.7+7*14<.@%~-
   tests =: 123 100 ; 23 47 ; 80 40 ; 62 62 ; 2145 1134
   (,. f/ each) tests
┌─────────┬───┐
│123 100  │14 │
├─────────┼───┤
│23 47    │0  │
├─────────┼───┤
│80 40    │21 │
├─────────┼───┤
│62 62    │7  │
├─────────┼───┤
│2145 1134│511│
└─────────┴───┘
```

Comment: In the future, please use TIO.run/nexus

Comment: @Pavel No, tio.run is v2, nexus is there only for v1 compatibility

Comment: @ASCII-only https://tio.run has a disclaimer at the bottom that all generated permalinks might break in the future. I think I should make that more prominent. Except for testing purposes, nobody should be using v2 at his moment.

Comment: @Dennis Oh, I didn't know! Will edit asap.

Answer (score 4):

## CJam, <s>13</s> <s>12</s> 15 bytes

- Saved a byte thanks to Martin Ender.
- Added 3 bytes thanks to Martin Ender.
- Changed `]` to `[` thanks to ETHproductions.

```
q~\-Ed/m[)7*0e>
```

Blatantly stole orlp and xnor's methods.

Input is the two numbers separated by a space: `100 123`

Explanation:

```
q~\-Ed/m])7*0e>
q~\-            e# Input two numbers, swap and subtract them.
    E           e# Push 0xE (15)
     d/m]       e# Float divide and take the floor.
         )7*    e# Increment and multiply by 7.
            0e> e# Max of this and 0.
```

Comment: `D` is only `13`. And you can save a byte by incrementing the value before multiplication instead of adding 7 afterwards.

Comment: @JamesHolderness The issue is that Python's integer division works rounds towards -inf whereas CJam's rounds towards zero.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but I thought `m]` is ceil; `m[` is floor.

Comment: @ETHproductions You're right, edited.

Answer (score 4):

## Excel VBA, <sub><s>24</s></sub> 17 Bytes

Immediates window function that takes input from cells `A1` and `B1` and outputs to the VBE immediates window.

```vb
?([A1-B1]\14)*7+7
```

**Subroutine Version, 43 Bytes**

takes input `b, c` as variant\integer and prints to the VBE immediates window

```vb
Sub a(b,c):Debug.?Int((c-b)/14)*7+7:End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia 0.5](http://julialang.org/), 26 bytes

```julia
v\w=max(fld(w-v,14)*7+7,0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/julia5#Lc5BCsIwEIXhtT3FUCgkOoGZJDZuFO/RdiHUQKFGqZp4@5iKu@/Bv3g59ul4u3yEn0eRVES2cut2Dklmf19AREwSpgCiYyJkbQaEzjr8g/BAK1qNrV7BbCxqtvvfIKRBVpvzY5nCy4u6UcxPUCdozLsPdUkiQippuSGraxjzFw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 14 bytes

```
V-U /2+7 f7 w0
```

[Run it here!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.3&code=Vi1VIC8yKzcgZjcgdzA=&input=MTEzNCwyMTQ1)

Thank you ETHproductions for shaving off 3 bytes!

Comment: Very nice. `f` accepts an argument and floors to a multiple of that number, so I think you can so `V-U /2+7 f7 w0` to save three bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, <s>41</s> 39 bytes

```
    <?=7*max(0,1+($argv[2]-$argv[1])/14|0);
```

takes input from command line arguments; run with `-r`.

<s>7</s> 5 extra bytes just to handle $a>$b :-/

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

```
-14÷>7*0M
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@69raHJ4u525loHv//@GhsYmXEaGJqYA)

**Explanation**

```
-          # push difference of inputs
 14÷       # integer divide by 14
    >      # increment
     7*    # times 7
       0   # push 0
        M  # take max
```

Or a corresponding function with same byte-count operating on a number-pair

```
Î¥14÷>7*M
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@3@479BSQ5PD2@3MtXz//482NDQ20TEyNDGNBQA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Dyalog APL](http://dyalog.com/download-zone.htm), 14 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

Takes `v1` as right argument and `v2` as left argument.

```apl
0⌈7×1+(⌊14÷⍨-)
```

`0 ⌈` the maximum of zero and

`7 ×` seven times

`1 + (`...`)` one plus...

`⌊` the floor of

`14 ÷⍨` a fourteenth of

`-` the difference (between the arguments)

[TryAPL online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=f%u21900%u23087%D71+%28%u230A14%F7%u2368-%29%20%u22C4%20123%20f%20100%20%u22C4%2023%20f%2047%20%u22C4%2080%20f%2040%20%u22C4%2062%20f%2062%20%u22C4%202145%20f%201134&run)

Answer (score 2):

## Befunge, 19 bytes

```
777+:&&\-+\/*:0`*.@
```

[Try it online!](http://befunge.tryitonline.net/#code=Nzc3KzomJlwtK1wvKjowYCouQA&input=MTEzNCAyMTQ1)

This relies on a slightly different formula to that used by orlp and xnor, since the Befunge reference interpreter has different rounding rules to Python. Befunge also doesn't have the luxury of a `max` operation.

The basic calculation looks like this:

```
x = (v2 - v1 + 14)/14*7
x = x * (x > 0)
```

Examining the code in more detail:

```
7                     Push 7                                      [7]
 77+:                 Push 14 twice.                              [7,14,14]
     &&               Read v1 and v2 from stdin.                  [7,14,14,v1,v2]
       \-             Swap the values and subtract.               [7,14,14,v2-v1]
         +            Add the 14 that was pushed earlier.         [7,14,14+v2-v1]
          \/          Swap the second 14 to the top and divide.   [7,(14+v2-v1)/14]
            *         Multiply by the 7 that was pushed earlier.  [7*(14+v2-v1)/14 => x]
             :        Make a copy of the result                   [x,x]
              0`      Test if it's greater than 0.                [x,x>0]
                *     Multiply this with the original result.     [x*(x>0)]
                 .@   Output and exit.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Go](http://golang.org), 36 bytes

`func(a,b int)int{return(b-a)/14*7+7}`

[Try it online!](https://play.golang.org/p/0eZ1UaF0_K)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 31 bytes

```
(a,b,c=(b-a)/14|0)=>c>0?c*7+7:0
```

```js
f=(a,b,c=(b-a)/14|0)=>c>0?c*7+7:0
document.write(f(1134,2145))
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, 31 bytes

`(a,b)->b<a?0:(a=(b-a)/2)+7-a%7;`

This is a lambda expression assignable to `IntBinaryOperator`.

a is your candidate's votes, b is your opponent's.

java rounds down for division with positive integers, so `+7-a%7` is used to bump up the value to the next multiple of 7.

Comment: `a->b->(b=(b-a)/14*7+7)>0?b:0` is 3 bytes shorter, but I kinda like your approach more, so +1 from me. Almost every answer given already uses `max((b-a)/14*7+7,0)`..

Comment: i prefer using lambdas that return the result directly. and yeahb everyone did the formula a bit shorter but this was how i reasoned about the answer before checking everyone elses

Comment: `a->b->(b=(b-a)/14*7+7)>0?b:0` does return the result directly as well: [Try it here.](https://tio.run/##jY4xb8IwEEb3/Iob7dIYG9KmKuBulRg6MVYdziZFTo1jkQsSqvjtqasGOpLtSfe@06vxiHkTq1Bvv3rrsW3hDV34zgBaQnIW6mSIjpwXn12w5JogXgdYrgNVu@pwP04aQGuwsIIec21yzcyKmRz5VBV35aTkWr6YZ9kvslQQO@NTwRBybNwW9imObejgwu79A5D/hgJsTi1Ve9F0JGI6kQ/MCozRn5iSkl9wNud8cWtQlBd/nH59/yRH6I8z/k@3daXmxTVHFQ9/k3N27n8A) Or do you mean you prefer single-method lambdas above currying lambdas; `(a,b)->` preference over `a->b->`, even though it's longer?

Comment: single method over currying, but thats just a personal preference

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby, <s>26</s> 27 bytes

```
->a,b{[(b-a)/14*7+7,0].max}
```

Basically the same as xnor's and orlp's Python solution, <s>with a twist (no need to add 7, because of negative modulo, saves 1 byte in ruby, don't know about python)</s>

No twist, the twist was just a bad case of cognitive dissonance. Forget it. Really. :-)

Answer (score 1):

## [Noodel](https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel), 16 [bytes](https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel/docs/code_page.html)

```
⁻÷14ɲL×7⁺7ḋɲl⁺÷2
```

Pulled equation from [xor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/106436/52270) and [orlp](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/106435/52270) answers, but since *Noodel* does not have a max capability had to work around that.

[Try it:)](https://tkellehe.github.io/noodel/editor.html?code=%E2%81%BB%C3%B714%C9%B2L%C3%977%E2%81%BA7%E1%B8%8B%C9%B2l%E2%81%BA%C3%B72&input=40%2C80&run=false)

#### How it works

```
⁻÷14ɲL×7⁺7       # The equation...
⁻                # v2 - v1
 ÷14             # Pops off the difference, then pushes on the (v2 - v1)/14
    ɲL           # Applies lowercase which for numbers is the floor function.
      ×7         # Multiplies that by seven.
        ⁺7       # Then increments it by seven.

          ḋɲl⁺÷2 # To relate with the other answers, this takes the max between the value and zero.
          ḋ      # Duplicates what is on the top of the stack (which is the value just calculated).
           ɲl    # Pops off the number and pushes on the magnitude (abs value).
             ⁺   # Add the abs to itself producing zero if the number came out negative (which means we are already winning).
              ÷2 # Divides the result by two, which will either be zero or the correct offset.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 31 bytes

```
(a,b)=>Math.max((b-a)/14*7+7,0)
```

The ternary version is 2 bytes longer

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 16 bytes

```
MtS+0[+7*7/-HG14
```

[Try it here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=MtS%2B0%5B%2B7%2A7%2F-HG14%3BghQeQ&input=100%2C123%0A47%2C23%0A40%2C80%0A62%2C62%0A1134%2C2145&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=100%2C123%0A47%2C23%0A40%2C80%0A62%2C62%0A1134%2C2145&debug=0)